# Is there a way to slow down the input update from a numericInput ui object

Tags: r, shiny, numeric-input

So as the title say I'm looking for a way to slow down the input update form a numericInput ui object.

As a little preface, I am developing an application where I have dynamically built numeric inputs using a map function based on a drop down choice selection of numbers 1-8. So based on how many numeric inputs the user wants to compare the server will dynamically build them. And, in order to display some descriptive statistics, I had to add a actionButton that updates tables built from reactive values.

The problem arises from when I'm looking to type values into the numeric input fields. I only have about 1 second from the initial number click to finish my typing my value until I get kicked out of the numeric input field. In order to finish the number I wish to type I have to click back into the field once or twice to finish typing out the number. Once I have the number typed, I can then hit my action button to update the tables.

How do I make the numeric input fields "sleep" until the button press pulls the values for the reactive tables. I've had to do several odd workarounds due to the nature of the dynamically built numeric inputs and reactive tables/plots. Any input is very welcome.

Comment: What about `debounce()` or `throttle()`?  These won't stop the rendering until the button is pressed, but it will give you more time.  If you can post a minimal reproducible example, we may be able to help more.

Comment: So debounce() and throttle() are a function on the reactive values. However, my issue lies in the numeric input field kicking me out. I'm not sure how to post a minimally reproducible example without posting my entire application. Although I did try both of them before realizing where the problem exists.

Comment: Sounds like your inputs have reactive dependencies. Use Reactive Log/Trace (https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html) to identify which elements are being re-rendered on value change - then refactor to remove dependencies (e.g.: using isolate). Alternatively, use an artificial control element like the answer from Stephane.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help without some code...

You can do something like that:

```r
go <- reactiveVal(FALSE)

observeEvent(input[["button"]], {
  go(TRUE)
})

output[["table"]] <- renderTable({
  req(go())
  something using the numeric inputs...
})
```

Does it help?